# tree = etree.fromstring(bytes(xml, encoding='utf-8')) TypeError: encoding without a string argument

Tags: python, regex, xml, xml-parsing

I would like to write a function which allows me to extract the value of the attribute "fmc" and the text inside the part "tag".  I will like to use a regex solution.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motives">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours" fmc="obstacle">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>
```

So I have modify this function to suit my data according to the answers above

code

```
def review_extractor(xml, category='verbatim', do_lower=False):
    """
    Extract review and label
    """
    # use lxml...

    # parse the xml snippet into an object tree
    tree = etree.fromstring(bytes(xml, encoding='utf-8'))
    # find all elements that have "fmc" attribute
    for e in tree.findall(".//*[@fmc]"):
        label = e.xpath("./@fmc")[0]
        for c in e.getchildren("./part"):
            # print value of "fmc" attribute and text of child element
            print(f"{label:15}{c.text}")
            # 
        return label, c.text
```

So For my example, the function should return this (review before label):

```
Label      review_text
motivation Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.

condition Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.

obstacle Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,

obstacle Je pense oui
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question ? Why use only regex for this?

Comment: It is a script for splitting data and I have to improve it for my data that's why and because I use the function in others functions to split the data in train, test and val. I put the rest of code above

Comment: Your indentation is not right; you need one more edit.

Comment: @kely789456123 I’m not sure how that relates to my comment, can you elaborate?

Comment: I reeddit the code

Comment: @AMC I rewrite my question.

Comment: Hi @kely789456123 you should not completely edit your question after people have spent time answering it. If you have another question please ask a new one!

Comment: Never use regular expressions to process XML. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

I realise you explicitly asked for a regex solution, but as an alternative here is one using one of pythons built in xml parsers, specifically [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

```
xml_string = """<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motives">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours" fmc="obstacle">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

for i in tree.findall('ver'):
    fmc = i.attrib.get("fmc")
    if fmc is None:
        continue
    for p in i.findall("part"):
        print(fmc, p.text)
```

The output is

```
motives Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.
condition Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.
obstacle Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,
obstacle Je pense oui
```

if you want to use xpath expressions, you can simplify it slightly further

```
for i in tree.findall('ver[@fmc]'):
    for p in i.findall('part'):
        print(i.attrib['fmc'], p.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `/fmc(.*?)+=(.*?)+\"(.+?)\"/g`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the regex:

```
<([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^\/]*?fmc=([\'\"])(.*?)\2.*?>[\s\n\r]*<([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?>(.*?)</\4>
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/b7AkIN/1)**.

The complete code looks like this:

```
import re

f = """<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motivation">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>"""

regex = r'<([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^\/]*?fmc=([\'\"])(.*?)\2.*?>[\s\n\r]*<([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?>(.*?)</\4>'

matches = re.findall(regex, f)

for x in matches:
    print(x[2] + " " + x[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is really the wrong solution for this but this could work:

```
fmc="(.*?)".*?<part.*?>(.*?)</part>
```

https://regex101.com/r/M7LJLU/1

And you desired result will be in `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: If you have another solution feel free to propose it I will try anything at this point

Comment: @kely789456123 you seem insistent on using regex so I provided a working solution. If you want the proper solution then look into [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and learn XPath

Answer (score 0):

This is job better suited to an XML parser. I use `untangle` from the `PyPI` repository:

```
import untangle

xml = """<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motives">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours" fmc="obstacle">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>
"""

doc = untangle.parse(xml)
for ver in doc.corpus.ver:
    if ver['fmc'] is None: continue
    print(f"id={ver['id']}, fmc={ver['fmc']}")
    for part in ver.part:
        print(f"   part={part.cdata}")
```

Prints:

```
id=30, fmc=motives
   part=Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.
id=54, fmc=condition
   part=Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.
id=897, fmc=obstacle
   part=Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,
   part=Je pense oui
```

Comment: Not "de gros parcs"? Like "des petit pois"?

Comment: Thank but I just want to return those with fmw value and not none

Comment: Sorry about that. That's a one-line change. I have made an update.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `lxml` to parse your XML? IMHO it's much easier to let lxml parse the xml and navigate the resulting element tree using e.g. XPath to find the things you want.

```bash
# install lxml
pip3 install lxml
```

```xml
# xml snippet
xml = """\
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<corpus>
    <ver id="18" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="1.3" type="discours">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW04_0">Ça existe sur des gros parcs Hlm mais c'est macro.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="30" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="2" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="motives">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW01_0">Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="54" etude="EC1_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="1" critere="" origine="IW" type="discours" fmc="condition">
        <part code="EC1_Elec_IW10_0">Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.</part>
    </ver>
    <ver id="897" etude="EC3_Elec" elec="oui" niveau="4" critere="4.1" origine="TR" type="discours" fmc="obstacle">
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,</part>
        <iwer>Çava influencer la demande pour ce type de solution c'est ça ?</iwer>
        <part code="EC3_Elec_TR2_1">Je pense oui</part>
    </ver>
</corpus>
"""
```

Then this is the code that does the trick!

```python
# use lxml...
from lxml import etree
# parse the xml snippet into an object tree
tree = etree.fromstring(bytes(xml, encoding='utf-8'))
# find all elements that have "fmc" attribute
for e in tree.findall(".//*[@fmc]"):
    label = e.xpath("./@fmc")[0]
    for c in e.findall("./part"):
        # print value of "fmc" attribute and text of all <part> elements
        print(f"{label:15}{c.text}")
```

Output:

```
motives        Avant 75 on n'a pas isolé puis après, au fur et à mesure des règlementations.
condition      Le deuxième boitier, il est où ? s'il y en a un qui est à l'intérieur et qui remplace un bout de l'isolation, il est caché OK.
obstacle       Avec l'économie d'énergie, on va imposer de plus en plus d'automatismes,
obstacle       Je pense oui
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. but I do not want text in <iwer> tag

Comment: updated the answer to only print text from <part> elements

Comment: hello what does {label:15} correspond to can I rewrite it like this in a function : return label:15 or it will false ?

Comment: It just pads spaces to the end up to 15 chars. you can just `print(label, c.text)`